# Django Forms without admin

Tags: django, forms

I am learning Django, I saw so many videos of DJango.

I just wanted to know one thing that can we create an app (like login app, or contact app) without registering it into in admin (admin.py).

Off course it should have model etc to save the contact details or login details etc. Is it possible in Django ?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't create your admin.py file or not register the model that you don't want to see there. Django admin is fully optional.

Comment: Thanks, however without registering in the admin it works fine with model.. ? Let me check this.

Comment: It will work as expected. You just won't have admin pages and that is the only difference.